# How to fix orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to fix orientation portrait or landscapeLeft like Youtube's full screen.
When a user click button, it was changed portrait or landscapeLeft.
and was fixed.
The user can control only by button.

accept Device orientation Portrait, Landscape Left in General
It's my code

AppDelegate

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window 
{
        if(restrictRotation)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        else
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

ViewController

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate->restrictRotation = restriction;
}

- (IBAction)rotateOrientationAction:(id)sender 
    {
        [self restrictRotation:NO];
        if(isPortrait){
            [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) forKey:@"orientation"];
            self.myNewScrollViewHeight.constant = self.view.frame.size.height - self.naviBar.frame.size.height - self.horizMenu.frame.size.height;
            self.portraitMenuView.hidden = YES;

        }else{

            [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) forKey:@"orientation"];
            self.myNewScrollViewHeight.constant = self.view.frame.size.height * 0.5;
            self.portraitMenuView.hidden = NO;
        }
        isPortrait = !isPortrait;
       [self restrictRotation:YES];
    }
```

If I click the button, it was changed landscapeLeft but not changed portrait again.

Thank you

Comment: What you have tried , share the code and what are the  difficulties you're facing.

Comment: edited code thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is not satisfied for `restrictRotation`, please check below code to desire result.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    isPortrait = YES;
}

-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}

- (IBAction)rotateOrientationAction:(id)sender
{
    if (isPortrait) {
        [self restrictRotation:NO];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) forKey:@"orientation"];
    } else {
        [self restrictRotation:YES];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) forKey:@"orientation"];
    }

    isPortrait = !isPortrait;
}
```

**Update :**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    isPortrait = YES;
}


- (IBAction)rotateOrientationAction:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.restrictRotation = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) forKey:@"orientation"];

    if (isPortrait)
    {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) forKey:@"orientation"];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) forKey:@"orientation"];
    }

    isPortrait = !isPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked well but I found one problem.
If I grab the device reverse orientation(portrait state -> grab landscape, landscape state -> grab portrait), it was not working. If I control the orientation. I should grab same orientation. 
I am sorry for my poor English skills.
Thank you

Comment: The device's orientation is Portrait in app.<-> Hardware's orientation is Landscape. -> click button -> it's not rotated

Comment: Have you check ?  @양홍범

Comment: Yes. I checked update! but still it's same. so removed fixation. I just accepted autoRotate. Thank you for your answer! Thank you so much! It helped me very well @iOS Dev